# In threejs, is there a property on a scene or mesh that refers the renderer?

Tags: three.js, mesh, scene, renderer

I want to pass a threejs mesh to another frameowork.  From that mesh, I want to access the threejs canvas.  This is available on the threejs renderer as the domElement property.  So my question is - can I get access to the threejs renderer from the mesh?  I can get any parents and find out if the parent is the scene.  So another way to ask is, is there access from a threejs scene to the renderer?  If not... it would nice to have that added.  This is to avoid passing two parameters, as ideally, I would like it to be just done with a single property.

Comment: A mesh doesn't belong to a renderer.

Comment: Just add your own property to the object's `userData`, wherever you feel it's appropriate. `mesh.userData = renderer;`

Answer (score 0):

Okay - so the answer is that a scene does not know its renderer.  Looking at the threejs code, I see now, that the renderer is not passed in to the scene it just operates on it in the update loop.